# how to rewrite this python SQL statement to SQL statement

Tags: sql

```
insert into accounts(member_id, currency, balance, locked)
select id, " + str(currency_id) + ", 0, 0 from members where id not in (select 
member_id from accounts where currency=" + str(currency_id)
```

lets assume 
currency, balance, locked
7, 0, 0 
if i want insert this currency for all members in accounts table

Comment: Need more details about your table schema.

Comment: Other than taking out the `\n` and replacing `str(currency_id)` with the currency_id you want, what problem are you having?

Comment: I got it working  , thanks @Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the number to string on SQL you may use `cast`. Please see below

```
select id,  cast(currency_id as varchar) , 0, 0 from members
where id not in (select member_id from accounts where currency=currency_id)
```